# Hook create / update post

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

I'm creating an Event thanks to a plugin (Event plus).

I need to alter the hook when the event is created, I tried with the native WP functions, but as WP (or the plugin ?) always create an ID for the post type (to save the draft automaticaly), the "updated" is always trigger.

I need to do some function if the event is a new, and some function if the event is an existing one. What should I change ?

```
    function wemap_update_create_event( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    if($post->post_type == "incsub_event"){
        nice($post);
        //check if the post is in the database or not with get_post( $post_id ) == null
        if( get_post( $post_id ) == null ) {
            die("not in db");
        }
        if($update && get_post( $post_id ) != null) {

            die("update");
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wemap_update_create_event', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `function wemap_update_create_event( $post_id, $post, $update ) { if ( $update ) { echo 'is post update'; } else { echo 'is new post'; } }` ?

Comment: Yes, the conditio is always true...

Comment: Are you sure? Because I tried it (except I use `error_log()` and not `echo`) and I got the correct status - `is post update` if the post is being updated; `is new post` if the post is new.

Comment: Absolutely, I think it's strange too... That's why I'm here ^^

Comment: Well, that's indeed strange.. have you checked the plugin docs? It probably has a hook for running custom actions when an event is created.. ?